# Tkinter window at the bottom all the time

Tags: python, tkinter, window, desktop, topmost

I already know `tkinter.Tk().attributes("-topmost", True)` which makes the window stay on top all the time. But is there some way to make the window stay at the bottom all the time? I mean something like `tkinter.Tk().attributes("-bottommost", True)` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no method in tkinter that forces the window to be below all other windows on the desktop.

Comment: How about the trick given in my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is not strictly a way to make a Tk window always underneath others. If your aim is to have a Tk application which cannot be seen, then you could achieve it by modiying the alpha value of the root window:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.attributes('-alpha', 0)
root.mainloop()
```

As this window is transparent, you could think of it as always underneath.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little trick, but you can think of something like this.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def lower_window(event):
    root.lower()

root.bind('<FocusIn>', lower_window)

root.mainloop()
```