# tkinter set window on bottom of all other windows as desktop widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, command-line

I'm using Python3 on ubuntu gnome 16.04.
I wrote a whole UI project using tkinter and now I'm stuck because I cant find a way to solve the next issue:

My question:
is there any way to set a window on the bottom of all other windows using tkinter?
so that when I press 'win' + 'd' shortcut and go back to the desktop I will see my widget running?

edit:
If tkinter does not support that, I would be glad to hear other solutions
to make my widget run on the bottom of other windows, in a way that my main GUI library will still be tkinter (I don't want to refactor all my project because on that) maybe adding bash commands that pin my window to the desktop, maybe using some other python window attributes libraries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter window at the bottom all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122453/tkinter-window-at-the-bottom-all-the-time)

Comment: I did not try to copy that question but to extend it.
I'm looking for a solution, maybe some other way to do this but still keep tkinter as my main GUI library

Comment: Maybe your window manager can do that but then you have to research what your window manager has to offer.